# Upper bound on intersection of $\ell_p$-norm balls in $\mathbb R^n$, with different centers and the same radius

Tags: real-analysis, integration, geometry, volume, geometric-probability

Let $x$ and $x'$  be points in $\mathbb R^n$ (for a large positive integer $n$) and let $d(x,x') := \sup_{1 \le j \le n} |x_j-x'_j|$ be their $\ell_\infty$-norm distance apart. Given $r \ge 0$, let $B(x;r) := \{z \in \mathbb R^n \mid d(x,z) \le r\}$ be the closed ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$.

> **Question.** What are good upper and lower bounds on the volume $v_n(x,x';r)$ of intersection of $B(x;r)$ and $B(x';r)$ as a function of $d(x,x')$, $r$, and $n$ ?

**Note.** By a [paper of M. Gromov](https://www.ihes.fr/%7Egromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/1658.pdf), we know that $v_n(x,x';r)$ is a decreasing function of $d(x,x')$.

---

**Motivation.** A lower bound on $v_n(x,x';r)$ would let me compute an upper bound for the [total-variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) $T_n(x,x';r)$ between the uniform distribution on $B(x;r)$ and the uniform distribution on $B(x';r)$. Indeed, by definition, one can easily obtain the formula
$$
T_n(x;x';r) = 1-\frac{v_n(x,x';r)}{(2r)^n}.
$$

Comment: Just double check. The ball $B(x;r)$ is defined by using $d$? Or still by using the Pythagorean ($\ell^2$-) norm?

Comment: Good point. I've made it explicit now.

Comment: Hmm... May I know which part of the paper indicate that $v_n$ is a decreasing function of $r$? Intuitively I would say it is *increasing* in $r$ though. Imagine $x$ and $x'$ are sufficiently far apart. Then for very small $r>0$ they won't even intersect.

Comment: That was a slip of pen. Should be "decreasing in $d(x,x')$".

Comment: I am wondering if we should begin with simple cases and try to generalize: for two closed discs (i.e. working in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and 'disc' under $l_\infty$ norm look like squares) say their intersection is nonempty, i.e. ($d(x,x') < 2r$). The intersection is a "rectangle" with base $d(x,x')$ and height at most $2r$. So in this case a bound on $v_2(x,x';r)$ would be $d(x,x') \cdot (2r)$.

Comment: Ya, cool. I just came up with something along those lines. It solves the complete problem too. Lemme write it down.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer.** *Sorry for self-answering, but the problem turns out to be really easy.*

So, we can write $B(x;r) := \{z \in \mathbb R^n \mid x_j - r \le z_j \le x_j + r\;\forall j\}$. Thus, we have the equivalance
$$
z \in B(x;r) \cap B(x';r) \iff z_j \in I_j\;\forall j,
$$
where $I_j: [c_j^-,c_j^+]$, with $c_j^- := \max(x_j,x'_j)-r$ and $c_j^+ := \min(x_j,x_j')+r$. That is, $B(x;r) \cap B(x';r)=I_1 \times \ldots \times I_n$, a cuboid. Note that $I_j$ is empty if $x_j \ge x'_j + 2r$ or $x_j' \ge x_j + r$; else it has length equal to $\min(x_j,x_j')-\max(x_j,x_j')+2r = 2r - |x_j-x_j'|$. Thus
$$
\begin{split}
v_n(x,x';r) := \text{vol}(B(x;r)\cap B(x';r)) &= \text{vol}(I_1\times \ldots \times I_n)= \Pi_{j=1}^n\text{length}(I_j)\\
&= \begin{cases}0,&\mbox{ if }d(x,x') \ge 2r,\\\Pi_{j=1}^n(2r-|x_j-x_j'|),&\mbox{else.}\end{cases}
\end{split}
$$

---

Thus, if $d(x,x') \ge 2r$ and we let $u_j := |x_j-x_j'|/(2r)$, then we immediately get
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{v_n(x,x';r)}{(2r)^n} &\ge \Pi_{j=1}^n\left(1-u_j\right) \ge e^{-\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{u_j}{1-u_j}}=e^{-\sum_{j=1}^n(1+u_j+u_j^2+\ldots)}\\
&=e^{-\sum_{p=1}^\infty\|u\|_p^p}=e^{-\sum_{p=1}^\infty\left(\frac{\|x-x'\|_p}{2r}\right)^p} \ge 1 -\sum_{p=1}^\infty\left(\frac{\|x-x'\|_p}{2r}\right)^p,
\end{split}
$$
which in turn yields

> $$
> \begin{split}
> 0 \le T_n(x,x';r) &:= 1-\frac{v_n(x,x';r)}{(2r)^n} \\
> &\le \begin{cases}1-e^{-\sum_{p=1}^\infty\left(\frac{\|x-x'\|_p}{2r}\right)^p} \le \sum_{p=1}^\infty\left(\frac{\|x-x'\|_p}{2r}\right)^p,&\mbox{if }\|x-x'\|_\infty \le 2r,\\1,&\mbox{ else.}
> \end{cases}
> \end{split}
> $$

Comment: I think you mean $\text{vol}(I_1 \times \cdots \times I_n)$.

Comment: Good catch, thanks. Fixed.